# Форматирование даты в js

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, сервер, дата

С сервера мне приходит

```
2016-06-15 12:12:47.000000
```

Как убрать нули, как отформатировать чтобы нулей не было?

Comment: отрезать функцией substr с конца 7 символов не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Если регуляркой, то можно так:

```
var preg = /\.(\d+)/;
console.log("2016-06-15 12:12:47.000000".replace(preg, ""));
```

Output:

```
2016-06-15 12:12:47
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var d = (new Date('2016-06-15 12:12:47.000000'))
```

и из него например, так

```
console.log(d.toLocaleString());
```